# chrome ask multiple time to allow use of speaker and mic for incoming call in twilio

Tags: twilio

I am creating a call center application ,and when a call come to twilio client on chrome browser it ask for permission to allow use of speaker and mic .When second call comes I have to allow it for two times and if third call come I have to allow three times and so on.

and in firfox browser ,when I acccept call second time it automatically disconnect and give error of mediastream.

Please suggest me where I am wrong and how to solve this problem.

Below is the javascript of twilio client,If need some more information please let me know

```
<script
```

type="text/javascript">

```
//var
token
=callaction();
var
connection=null;
var
content;
$(document).ready(function(){
$('#hangupcallbutton').hide();
$.post('cleanify?action=createcall',
function(data){
content=
data;
Twilio.Device.setup(content,
{
debug:
true}
);
}
);
Twilio.Device.ready(function
(device)
{
$("#log").text("Ready");
}
);
Twilio.Device.error(function
(error)
{
$("#log").text("Error:
"
+
error.message);
}
);
Twilio.Device.connect(function
(conn)
{
//alert("connect
handler");
$("#log").text("Successfully
established
call");
connection
=
conn;
}
);
Twilio.Device.disconnect(function
(conn)
{
//alert("in
disconnect");
$("#callbutton").html('Call');
$("#callbutton").removeClass("btn-danger
").addClass("btn-success");
//
$("#callbutton").toggleClass('btn-danger
btn-success');
$("#log").text("Call
ended");
$('#RejectCallButton').show();
$('#acceptcallbutton').show();
$('#hangupcallbutton').hide();
$('#myModal').modal('hide');
}
);
Twilio.Device.incoming(function
(conn)
{
//
alert("in
incomming");
connection
=
conn;
$("#log").text("aa
rahi
h
call");
$('#myModal').modal('show');
$('#incomingnumber').html(conn.parameters.From);
$('#RejectCallButton').click(function()
{
connection.reject();
}
);
$('#acceptcallbutton').click(function()
{
connection.accept();
$('#RejectCallButton').hide();
$('#acceptcallbutton').hide();
$('#hangupcallbutton').show();
}
);
$('#hangupcallbutton').click(function()
{
$('#RejectCallButton').show();
$('#acceptcallbutton').show();
$('#hangupcallbutton').hide();
connection.disconnect();
}
);
//
accept
the
incoming
connection
and
start
two-way
audio
}
);
Twilio.Device.cancel(
function
(conn)
{
//alert("in
cancel");
connection
=
conn;
$('#myModal').modal('hide');
}
);
$.each(['0','1','2','3','4','5','6','7','8','9','star','pound'],
function(index,
value)
{
$('#button'
+
value).click(function(){
//alert("hello");
if(connection)
{
if
(value=='star')
connection.sendDigits('*')
else
if
(value=='pound')
connection.sendDigits('#')
else
connection.sendDigits(value)
return
false;
}
}
);
}
);
//
Do
something
with
c
alert(content);
}
);
function
callhandle(){
if($("#callbutton").html().trim()
==
'Call'){
$("#callbutton").html('HangUp');
$("#callbutton").removeClass("btn-success").addClass("btn-danger");
//
$("#callbutton").toggleClass('btn-success
btn-danger');
call();
}
else
if($("#callbutton").html().trim()
==
'HangUp'){
hangup();
$("#callbutton").html('Call');
$("#callbutton").removeClass("btn-danger").addClass("btn-success");
//
$("#callbutton").toggleClass('btn-danger
btn-success');
}
}
function
call()
{
//
get
the
phone
number
to
connect
the
call
to
//
get
the
phone
number
to
connect
the
call
to
//
alert(
$("#selectOutgoing").val());
params
=
{"PhoneNumber":
$('.dialnumber').val(),"From":
$("#selectOutgoing").val(),"isclient":
"true"}
;
Twilio.Device.connect(params);
}
function
hangup()
{
Twilio.Device.disconnectAll();
}

</script>
```

Comment: Twilio Evangelist here. From looking at your code, it looks like you are doing things correctly. Could you clarify exactly when the Allow Speaker and Mic dialog is showing up and whether or not the page has been reloaded in between?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From my experience, Chrome will only store those settings over HTTPS. Over HTPP Chrome will not store the settings thus it will prompt for the permissions every time

Answer (score 0):

It might happen after a call before initialize twilio when you get another call . So , you must initialize first .